# Comparing records in one table to another for large databases in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MySQL database. Lets say there are 1800 records in table 1 and 20000 records in table 2. Now I want to compare each record in table 1 to table 2 and update some fields in table 2 for the records that are matched.

I want to know what is the most optimized way to do this.

Comment: Do you have any code ?

Comment: The question is: how exact do you want to compare? Can you use JOIN?

Comment: I havent started coding yet. Just now,I got the requirement.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz: Can join be used? I want to compare Part Number in both the tables

Comment: That's what I asked ;) It depends how exact you can match the criterias. For perfect matches (ie. foreign key/primary key) see Asaphs post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient operation would be an update statement using a join. Something like this:

```
UPDATE table_2 AS t2
INNER JOIN table_1 AS t1 ON t1.some_id = t2.some_id
SET t2.some_col = t1.some_col;
```

Comment: This looks cool. I am gonna try this! Thanks

Comment: lol, very anxious, make sure you backup your tables first.

Comment: @Asaph: Works perfectly!!Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -2):

```
<?PHP
$lim = 5;
$limit = (int)$_GET['page']*$lim;
$res = mysql_query("select * from table1 limit $limit,$lim");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$som = $row['som'];
$id= $row['id'];
mysql_query("update table2 set somerow = $som where id=$id");
}
echo "<a href='?page=".$_GET['page']+1."'>Next</a>";
?>
```

Comment: dont recommend the use of the depreciated mysql API

Comment: edited and optimized. but you can use javascript redirect instead a href

Comment: and now you added an SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: edited and detacted SQL injection

Comment: You are still using a deprecated library. That's not a good recommendation. And there is a very clean single query solution for this question, so there is no need for an inefficient loop. Your solution need 1800/5=360 more queries than necessary.